# Replicating Drag & Drop testing with drag events, DataTransfer & Cypress JS

Tags: javascript, cypress, data-transfer

I'm trying to test drag and drop functionality on a React application using Cypress.
I monitored the dev tools event listener during my manual testing and can see 3 drag events: **dragenter, dragover and drop**.
DragOver contains the DataTransfer info of items and types. If I don't mock DT these values are missing when running my test, so I used Object.defineProperty to add them.

```
const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();

  Object.defineProperty(dataTransfer, 'items', {
    value: [{
      kind: 'string',
      type: 'pinnable_chart',
    }],
  });

  Object.defineProperty(dataTransfer, 'types', {
    value: ['pinnable_chart'],
  });

  cy.wrap(subject.get(0))
    .trigger('dragstart', 'center', {
      force: true,
      dataTransfer,
    })

  cy.wrap(target.get(0))
    .trigger('dragenter', 'topRight', {
      dataTransfer,
    })
    .trigger('dragover', 'topRight', {
      dataTransfer,
    })
    .trigger('drop', 'topRight', {
      force: true,
    });

  cy.wrap(subject.get(0)).trigger('dragend', 'center', {
    dataTransfer,
    force: true,
  });
```

No dragging or dropping is happening with my code. In the screenshot you'll see the difference between manual test (on the left) and running via Cypress (on the right).

What am I missing to get these drag events to work?

[image]